# Open a normal <a> link into an IFRAME

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want a link to load into an iframe when the user clicks it. I have tried the following code, but unfortunately that did not work. I want to do this without using Javasvript or JQuery. I have the jquery code that can do this task, but I want to do this in simple html. Moreover, I aslo want to get the ID of the element on which the user clicked before generating the frame.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

```
<a href="#frame" name="click">clickme</a>
<iframe src="login.html" name="frame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant get a popup in simple Html any way.Your idea of refering to another frame is good,but it will not popup .please read the Query http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-45236.html

Answer (score 3):

You can "popup" into a new window/tab by using the `target` attribute of the `<a>` tag. However if you want a popup window inside the same browser window, you will need to use javascript.

Comment: Yes i know that target="_blank" will cause it to  a new window/tab.But I want to find a way to get a popup without using JS.

Comment: `target="_blank"` *is* 'without using JS', I don't think you know what you want...

Comment: Does _blank Popup?The answer is no.it will only open it new Tab or window,Poput means to open in an Iframe

Answer (score 1):

If all you mean is "load into an iframe" then you just need to use the "target" attribute of the link. This will load the href into the iframe (though any "popping out" would have to be handled in js). The link should look like:

```
<a href="[page to show in the iframe]" target="frame">clickme</a>
<iframe src="login.html" name="frame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dom parser, and rebuild the HTML with the links as an iframes

or use some nasty str_replace calls to make anchors iFrames

```
$url=str_replace("<a ","<iframe ",$url);
$url=str_replace("</a> ","</iframe> ",$url);
```

I wouldn't do that tho. I would use js or jquery to rebuild them or create a lightbox with the iframe upon clicking the link. Good luck!